# XPath: contains(./text(), 'str') will look only into the first text descendent

Tags: xml, text, xpath, contains

I'm trying to write an XPath query that will select an element, whose text contains given string:

```
<div>Text1<strong>censored</strong>Text2</div>
```

So the following query wont match

```
//div[contains(./text(), 'Text2')]/strong/text()
```

But this one will, the text node index is explicitly stated:

```
//div[contains(./text()[2], 'Text2')]/strong/text()
```

how do I write a query that will match any text descendent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//div[text()[contains(., 'Text2')]]/strong/text()
```

Comment: I only want to search within text nodes of `div`. your query will also look into all the descendents of div and yield unwanted results